# Global variable in JS file not updated in QML files

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have two QML files, which uses a shared JavaScript file. The JavaScript
file declares a global variable - well that is what I believed it was, but in 
reality, it is global to the QML file it is used from.

Try running it, and you will see that main.qml and palayer.qml each seems
to have their own local instance of the global variable.

Now the question is, is this my logic that is not good or a bug?
And if it is my logic , how do I get a  global variable ?

```
              main.qml

              MouseArea {

                    id:mouse
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                           console.log("Value var selection" + Logic.selection)
                           if (Logic.selection === true)

                           {
                                selectInclude.visible = true
                                Logic.selection = false
                                console.log("Value rouge" + Logic.selection)
                            }

                            else
                           {
                               selectInclude.visible = false
                               Logic.selection = true
                               console.log("Value not selected" + Logic.selection)
                             }

                     }
```

And in my js file :

```
//control.js
.pragma library
var selection = true;
```

my second QML file : Player.qml i used the variable which is updated normally but nothing ....

```
Image {


    id: image5
    x: 685
    y: 373
    source:

        if (Logic.selection )
            {

            //console.log("value de selection" + Logic.selection)
             image5.source="images/ic_shuffle_on.png"

            }
       else
            {
             image5.source = "images/ic_shuffle.png"

             }
```

Comment: AFAIK, to load the library means, to run the file once in the scope of the file. What you want to achieve could be done by a singleton object. A good start on that, you can find here: http://imaginativethinking.ca/make-qml-component-singleton/

Comment: And don't use your strange `if-else`-construct there. Use the ternary operator: `(Logic.selection ? 'images/ic_shuffle_on.png' : 'images/ic_shuffle.png')` or at least `return 'images/....png'` instead of `image5.source = 'images/....png'`

Comment: @derM He declared it shared as presemted [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#shared-javascript-resources-libraries) and it should be fine. Anyhow OP doesn't show a fully working code so it's hard to tell what's going wrong. Could it be [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42102?focusedCommentId=265730&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-265730)?

Comment: Thanks @BaCaRoZzo. I was not aware of this feature.

Comment: @derM thanks, i will try to use singleton as you said.